# How do I locate the Google Maps URL present inside the iframe element via Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, seleniumwire

I wish to retrieve the Google Maps URL present inside the iframe element of a webpage https://villageinfo.in/andaman-&-nicobar-islands/nicobars/car-nicobar/arong.html.

Below is the sample url which I need from the iframe element.
https://maps.google.com/maps?ll=9.161616,92.751558&z=18&t=h&hl=en-GB&gl=US&mapclient=embed&q=Arong%20Andaman%20and%20Nicobar%20Islands%20744301

I am unable to retrieve URL when I performed below steps. Page has only 1 iframe element.

```
iframe = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('iframe')
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

I even tried to retrieve all urls inside the element, but it gave Google Ads URLs apart from the one I require.

```
urls = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'a')
for url in urls:
    print(url.get_attribute('href'))
```

What should be the approach or methodology here to be tried?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can't get elements inside Google Maps iframe because of browser `CORS` policy.

[Reference to CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

So Selenium gets empty iframe, because further requests to frame's `contentWindow` are rejected by browser.

However, you can simply construct google map link by parsing data from parent iframe.

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("https://villageinfo.in/andaman-&-nicobar-islands/nicobars/car-nicobar/arong.html")

map = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[src*='google.com/maps']")))
mapUrl = map.get_attribute('src')
parsed_url = urlparse(mapUrl)
query_params = parse_qs(parsed_url.query)
query_part = query_params.get('q')
search_url = "https://www.google.com/maps/place/{}".format(query_part[0])
driver.get(search_url)
```

Google Maps iframe url contains param 'q' that can be used to get needed location and search for it directly from Google endpoint.

So you just need to extract it and paste inside URL.
In my code I get it via getting iframe `src`, getting it's param `q` and build new URL, using extracted param.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful solution. Here, I wanted to get Google Maps' URL was to obtain lat-long of the village. The search_url variable gets me the indirect URL which when called upon, gives the lat-long after 3-4 seconds of wait. Is there any other way/method/library we can directly retrieve the URL that contains like one in below.

https://www.google.com/maps/place/Arong,+Andaman+and+Nicobar+Islands+744301/@9.1618404,92.7509272,17z/data=!4m6!3m5!1s0x3064a0967df4bf01:0x1169b822b24e88b9!8m2!3d9.1615122!4d92.7518495!16s%2Fg%2F11bv3c9l7y?entry=ttu